# Mod rewrite htaccess - two variables in rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I found this solution online:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/([^-]*)/$ index.php?page=$1&link=$2 [L]

#dodaje slash na koncu
RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

The first one RewriteRule works perfect, it returns me `$_GET['page']=130`. But when it comes to second one, it returns me `$_GET['page']=index.php` instead of `$_GET['page']=130` and `$_GET['link']=35`. That finish with SQL error, because of numeric id of page.

Normal link looks like:

`?page=136`

`?page=136&link=35`

Rewrited one:

`/136/` - works

`/136/35/` - doesn't work, `$_GET['page']=index.php`

Comment: What **exactly** are the urls you're trying to reach ?

Comment: [link](http://rezultat.com.pl/test/?page=130&link=35) <- without rewrite [link](http://rezultat.com.pl/test/130/35) <- with rewrite, doesn't work

Comment: Are you trying to reach `/130/35` or `/130/35/` ? Because your rule only matches if there's a trailing slash

Comment: Nope, `RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]` adds slash at end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace your current code by this one (your htaccess has to be in `test` folder, and it's the same for `index.php`)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

# add trailing slash if no trailing slash and not an existing file/folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?page=$1&link=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

You can try these links

- `http://domain.com/test/136/35/` internally **rewrites** to `index.php?page=136&link=35`
- `http://domain.com/test/136/35` **redirects** to `http://domain.com/test/136/35/`
- `http://domain.com/test/136/` internally **rewrites** to `index.php?page=136`
- `http://domain.com/test/136` **redirects** to `http://domain.com/test/136/`

Comment: Thanks man. That works perfectly. It was all about order of rewrites?

Comment: Well you had many errors in your code. I've rewritten your trailing-slash-rule and changed your patterns in your two rules (the order is not important with this code)